# GIT warning: too many files skipping inexact rename detection

Tags: git, git-merge, git-config

I am aware that the default rename limit is 100 and we can increase this value using the config `diff.renamelimit config`

What I am worried about is that, if this config is not setup, will there be a wrong merge or any missing code?
I am trying to merge (git merge) 2 branches that have huge changes.

Can someone throw more light about this config setting?

Comment: I had the same experience, and I can confirm the message is simply a warning with no consequences other than a few pesky merge conflicts.

Comment: I have this warning on diff command

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Your content is safe.

As I understand it, `git` doesn't actually have any concept of a first-class `rename` operation (only `bzr` does, of the big 3 DVCSs): the `mv` is sugar on top of the underlying machinery, which is basically an `add` and a `rm`. Since `git` can track the content that changes during such operations, though, it can use heuristics to guess when an `add` and a `rm` are actually a `mv`. Since that takes way more work than just displaying what `git` actually recorded—the docs for `git-diff`explain that it "...require O(n^2) processing time where n is the number of potential rename/copy targets"—`git` won't try it when too many files are involved. The setting you mention just controls that threshold.

Comment: "Your content is safe" - though if the detection misses a file which was renamed on one side of a merge and changed on the other, you'll get merge conflicts which you might not have gotten had the rename been detected. The merge won't be *wrong*, but it might require more user effort to complete.

Comment: Thanks Hank and Jefromi.

Will setting up this "diff.renamelimit config" really be useful in any situations?

Comment: If someone is wondering too if this setting is useful: yes, it can help you merge branches when in one branch you have moved hundreds of files and in other you made a lot of changes in those files. I had situation like that when I had huge code refactor on one branch and some ongoing work on other.

Answer (score 81):

In case this helps anyone, I had a lot of files (hundreds, if not thousands) in one branch, which were not yet in the other branch. Running

```
$ git config merge.renamelimit 15345
```

made the below error when merging go away

```
$ git merge master
.
.
.
warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
warning: you may want to set your merge.renamelimit variable to at least 15345 and retry the command.
```

Comment: Also, after setting the rename limit, before retrying merge, call "git merge --abort" to abort the current merge in progress.